# Why do clones just run into battles and get shot at and just keep shooting?

Tags: star-wars, warfare, attack-of-the-clones

Why do they do keep on showing when getting shot at? Why do they also run into battles without taking cover?

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of reasons for this:

1. A new, very large army with new untested generals with limited
   battlefield knowledge, especially on such a vast scale.
2. Against an equally vast army.
3. On a planet where the terrain is not known.
4. The army was deployed in a rush to rescue the jedi on geonosis
5. The opposition forces are trying to escape and the battle is for all intents and purposes a pursuit, leaving not much time to take cover.

Tactics seem to be employed a bit more in the subsequent film and in the Clone Wars cartoon series